# Need a Warning pop up message in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to use a VBA code to pop up a warning message in the start of my database and tell me the name of people that their ages passed 50 just for once the last i could reach is that

```
 For i = 1 To 4    

If [Forms]![1]![years] >=50 Then 

MsgBox "employees:" & Me.name

End If
Next i
```

Comment: This is moot. You shouldn't have to warn against people above 50. Many of us are alive and well.

Comment: @Gustav: Indeed we are. :D

Comment: @Amr: your question is very unclear. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Andre i got sorry for bad grammar I just want a Code in VBA to show me a warning message to tell me the people whom reach 50 years today i already have a query contain (Name- age- phone)so all i need when i open my database a pop up message tell me the names of people and i want it to appear for once for each person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my simple function:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

And a loop in the click event of a button on your form (example):

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
End If
While Not rs.EOF
    If AgeSimple(Nz(rs!DOB.Value, Date)) >= 50 Then
        MsgBox "Employee: " & rs![Name].Value, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "50+"
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
Set rs = Nothing
```

Of course, replace the field/control names here with those of your actual form.

**Edit**

A demo is [here](https://cactusdata-my.sharepoint.com/personal/gustav_cactus_dk/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=021eafa982bbd48629335af8f67275cfe&authkey=ATxcJw9HIb5zt91AHjuWnlE)

Comment: So in the first function i put it as it is or change something

Comment: No, use it as it is.

Comment: i wrote it like that but didn't work is something missing ?

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
While Not rs.EOF
    If AgeSimple(Me!m6.Value) >= 50 Then
        MsgBox "Employee: " & Me![m1].Value, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "50+"
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
Set rs = Nothing

Comment: Check if m6 is of data type Date and contains valid dates.

Comment: yes it contains date/time format (Short time) could you upload a simple database file

Comment: I noticed a few bugs in the code. Please see edit. Also, a demo is now at the link.

Comment: You are the best (Y)

Comment: i faced a error as i have 50 field already existing and i just filled 20 so in the end of the last person name it show in VBA error = NuLL i know as the empty fields

Comment: now in reports when i want to preview my report it show me all fields + the empty one's is there a way to hide the empty fields to not show while printing am really very appreciate your help

Comment: That sounds like another issue so please open a new question with enough and updated information.